How to compile Shopware administration with VUE production mode?
Compiling Shopware administration for prodution env I get npm warn config production Use "--omit=dev" instead. and the browser console logs You are running Vue in development mode. for the admin dashboard page.
Where to add the npm option?
Where to turn off dev mode?
